# How to explain the cold

Tags: creative-writing

How could one explain breathing when it's really cold outside and you can see your breath? I just can't find a good way to word it.

Comment: Your breath is kind of like blossoming vapor. It's like a baby cloud that disappears before you can study it too hard.

Comment: Why do you need to explain it?  What does it have to do with your story?  Is it important to the character breathing?  Is it important to the reader?  What do you intend for the reader to feel when reading about your character breathing in the cold air?

Comment: Also, sometimes it is so cold that the slight movement of your cheeks when breathing stings and the air almost burns your lungs with each breath.

Comment: Im using it to try and explain the fact that my character is cold in her own house and cant afford the heat

Comment: Rephrasing or "what to write" questions are generally considered off-topic here. Which, I believe has been pointed out to you before, @Kae ? English SE has some leniency on questions regarding the finding of right words, but even there this would probably be too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The biting cold filled* [his/her] *lungs with every breath of the stale air that filled the small home. The warm exhale was more palatable, but* [he/she] *braced for fresh shards of ice to stab* [his/her] *throat again.*

Thought I might exaggerate a bit. Not sure how cold you were going for.

Answer (score 2):

It's called "vapor", "breath vapor", "[they] can see [their] breath", "exhaled steam", "frosty breath" etc...

imho this is better suited for English SE.

Answer (score 0):

Brrrrrrrrrrr!.....

Brrrrrrrrrrr!.....

T'was so cold her breath instantly formed icicles, sharp fingertips of hardened ice that skewered her chest and froze her blood and congealed her heart; and in her last moments, tears formed in the corners of her eyes, made solid by the prevailing cold, and oh! wonders!!! they formed as pearls, beautiful wonderous pearls...

... that could have been sold to buy a $10 dollars heater, or wood to burn,  and a lot more to spare, but no, alas, the author wants the melodrama of a little poor matchstick girl dying frozen,,. boo hoo hoo She can't even afford  heat